# Double vertical bar in haskell pattern matching?

Tags: haskell

Why does the following piece of code need to have two vertical bars `||`?

```
data Tree = Leaf Int
      | Node Tree Int Tree

occurs               :: Int -> Tree -> Bool
occurs m (Leaf n)     = m==n
occurs m (Node l n r) = m==n
                    || occurs m l
                    || occurs m r
```

Comment: That's the OR operator, not a pattern matcher

Comment: It's really poorly indented, so I understand your confusion. But it's just the usual Boolean `(||)` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` is the logical or operator. It bails out early if it evaluates to `True` and doesn't further search the tree.

Another way to implement it is to use the function [or](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:or) that may make it more readable:

```hs
occurs               :: Int -> Tree -> Bool
occurs m (Leaf n)     = m==n
occurs m (Node l n r) = or [m==n, occurs m l, occurs m r]
```

A small test:

```
λ> t = Node (Node (Leaf 1) 3 (Leaf 2)) 4 (Leaf 5)
λ> occurs 10 t
False
λ> occurs 3 t
True
```